# Angular 8 project and I am having trouble getting a value in a json object to display on my template in an ngFor loop

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

Sorry for my ignorance with the terms but I am mostly self-taught, well udemy to get started and then stackoverflow to get through the hard stuff. Usually, I find answers here without asking questions. This site is essential and very appreciated.

Now onto my troubles.

**I am building a quick CRM in angular 8** using a cloud service for the backend, aws. It is for my medical billing company. In these crazy times, we all need to upgrade our processes ;)

**I am using a nosql database, dynamodb,** and some of my fields are json objects, AWSJSON, on the backend.

I am using data models.

Here is my practice.model.ts file I have tried it a few different ways. Here are two examples and I tried to change them from strings to JSON objects.

```
## First One Tried ##
export interface Practice { 
 id: string;
 demographics: string;
 numbers: string;
 social: string;
 emailCampaign: string;
 history: string;
}
## Second ##
export interface Practice { 
 id: string;
 demographics: {
   practiceName: string,
   practiceSpecialty: string,
   practicePhone: number,
   practiceEmail: string
 };
 numbers: string;
 social: string;
 emailCampaign: string;
 history: string;
}
```

**I am building out the doctor-list page. It displays like this.**

Doctor list

[image: Doctor list]

Not sure if the model even needed to change, anyway.

**My question is** what's the best way to only display the value, not the whole json string?

Here is my HTML

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let practice of practices; let i = index">
  <th scope="row">{{practice.numbers}}</th>
  <td>{{practice.demographics}}</td>
  <td class="red-text"><a class=""  [routerLink]="['/edit-practice/', practice.id]" >Practice {{practice.id}}</a ></td>
  <td>{{practice.demographics}}<br class="mb-2">
    {{practice.demographics}} </td>
  <td>
    <div class="mt-2">
      <a mdbBtn  class="mr-3 green-text" [routerLink]="['/practice/', practice.id]" floating="true"><mdb-icon fas icon="file-invoice-dollar" size="lg"></mdb-icon></a>
      <a
        (click)="onDelete(practice.id)"
        mdbBtn
        floating="true"
        class="red-text">
        <mdb-icon fas icon="trash-alt" size="lg"></mdb-icon>
      </a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

For some reason {{practice.demographics.practiceName}} does not work. Do i need to use split() or is there a more elegant way?

```
export class ListPracticeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MdbTableDirective, { static: true }) mdbTable: 
  MdbTableDirective;
  practices: any;
  isLoading = false;
  private practicesSub: Subscription;
  private searchText: string;
  private previous: string;
  headElements = ['Numbers', 'Demos', 'ID'];
  constructor(public practiceService: PracticeService, private api: 
  APIService) { }
  @HostListener('input') oninput() { this.searchItems(); }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.api.ListPractices(null, 500).then((evt) => {
    console.log(evt.items);
    this.practices = evt.items;
    console.log(this.practices);
    this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.practices);
    this.previous = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
  });
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
  searchItems() {
    const prev = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
    if (!this.searchText) {
      this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.previous);
      this.practices = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
    }
    if (this.searchText) {
      this.practices = this.mdbTable.searchLocalDataBy(this.searchText);
      this.mdbTable.setDataSource(prev);
    }
  }
  onDelete(visitId: string) {
    this.practiceService.deleteVisit(visitId);
  }

}
```

ListPractices

```
  async ListPractices(
filter?: ModelPracticeFilterInput,
limit?: number,
nextToken?: string
): Promise<ListPracticesQuery> {
  const statement = `query ListPractices($filter: ModelPracticeFilterInput, $limit: Int, $nextToken: String) {
    listPractices(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      __typename
      items {
        __typename
        id
        demographics
        numbers
        social
        emailCampaign
        contact1 {
          __typename
          id
          demographics
          numbers
          social
          emailCampaign
          history
          moreInfo
        }
        contact2 {
          __typename
          id
          demographics
          numbers
          social
          emailCampaign
          history
          moreInfo
        }
        contact3 {
          __typename
          id
          demographics
          numbers
          social
          emailCampaign
          history
          moreInfo
        }
        history
        note {
          __typename
          id
          content
          moreInfo
        }
        moreInfo
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }`;
const gqlAPIServiceArguments: any = {};
if (filter) {
  gqlAPIServiceArguments.filter = filter;
}
if (limit) {
  gqlAPIServiceArguments.limit = limit;
}
if (nextToken) {
  gqlAPIServiceArguments.nextToken = nextToken;
}
const response = (await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(statement, gqlAPIServiceArguments)
)) as any;
return <ListPracticesQuery>response.data.listPractices;
}
```

Here is the console.log in google dev console

```
Array(7)
0: {__typename: "Practice", id: "fec9d19d-af3c-4d83-93e0-47d60cb7c647", demographics: "{"practiceSpecialty":null,"practiceName":"Practice 3","practicePhone":null,"practiceEmail":null}", numbers: "{"groupNpi":null,"providerNpi":null}", social: "{}", …}
1: {__typename: "Practice", id: "726afbd3-ee8a-45a1-8e0c-e50a5389e28b", demographics: "{"practiceSpecialty":"Primary Care","practiceName"…":"7275551234","practiceEmail":"jacob@jacob.com"}", numbers: "{}", social: "{}", …}
2: {__typename: "Practice", id: "e47c7596-c416-4c8d-af78-ca8df738e5ec", demographics: "{"practiceSpecialty":"Primary","practiceName":"ABC…":"7275555555","practiceEmail":"jacob@gmail.com"}", numbers: "{"groupNpi":"12345","providerNpi":"123456"}", social: "{}", …}
3: {__typename: "Practice", id: "c7cf847a-2360-4571-a87b-ea08befa4c5d", demographics: "{"practiceSpecialty":"Internal Medicine","practice…:"7277973798","practiceEmail":"jlaguna4@aol.com"}", numbers: "{"groupNpi":"1215206560","providerNpi":"1881683878"}", social: "{}", …}
4: {__typename: "Practice", id: "b95106e6-8e84-494a-a8a2-f847e10dc152", demographics: "{"practiceSpecialty":"Primary Care","practiceName"…ne":"practice","practiceEmail":"jacob@gmail.com"}", numbers: "{"groupNpi":"123456","providerNpi":"123456"}", social: "{}", …}
5: {__typename: "Practice", id: "83a4e0c6-4ef7-42f5-a835-ef742ab5b8a7", demographics: "{"practiceSpecialty":"Primary Care","practiceName"…":"7275555555","practiceEmail":"jacob@gmail.com"}", numbers: "{}", social: "{}", …}
6: {__typename: "Practice", id: "0c058f05-b017-4a90-be0a-e94b77ba52ad", demographics: "{"practiceSpecialty":"Oncology","practiceName":"Te…16093","practiceEmail":"zeferino34233@yahoo.com"}", numbers: "{"groupNpi":"123","providerNpi":"1992738058"}", social: "{}", …}
```

length: 7
**proto**: Array(0)

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you receive JSON data from your backend?

Comment: Sure, I added it in. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also share what is inside `this.api.ListPractices` method?

Comment: Sure, it is an auto-generated method made by aws amplify. It returns demographics as a string.

Comment: Interesting so far looks okay. One last piece. Can you share the Json response that you receive from your backend. I suspect that `demographics` is not recognized as json.

Comment: I was going to do that but forgot. It's up there. Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: The demographics objects are wrapped in quotes. I think that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the following change after this line:

```
this.practices = evt.items;
```

Iterate through practices and manually parse each time the `demographics` member.

```
this.practices.forEach(practice => {
    practice.demographics = JSON.parse(practice.demographics);
});
```

after this you should have demographics object with fields not just the string.

Then in your html change the binding as @John Peters wrote to:

```
{{practice.demographics.practiceName}}
```

Comment: I was close too. For some reason, my mind always skips over iteration. I was up to JSON.parse(practice.demographics) before asking for help. I try lol. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 1):

I think your practices are Observables, so you need to use async pipe in your template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let practice of practices | async; let i = index">
```

then, in your html, you say your column to display the entire object **practice.demographics** instead **practice.demographics?.practiceName**

- Try to use "?" for objects in template, to avoid errors if object is null or undefined
- Be sure that all model fields come from your json value (with first letter lowercase)
- use custom class/interface for Demographics object

  export interface Practice { 
                 id: string;
                 demographics: Demographics;
                 numbers: string;
                 social: string;
                 emailCampaign: string;
                 history: string;
      }

  ```
      export interface Demographics {
         practiceName: string,
         practiceSpecialty: string,
         practicePhone: number,
         practiceEmail: string
      }
  ```

Comment: Looks like no Observables are involved.

Comment: I built this code using multiple tutorials from udemy and youtube. I might have a few things in the code that are not needed. Any suggestions helps. Thanks for the suggesiton

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to Practice.Demographics for each td. Change that binding to Practice.Demographivs.practiceName etc.